# Como corregir un spinner que no se muestra bien en android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

tengo un problema con dos spinner que no se muestran de forma correcta, en la interfaz, en el simulador los dos ultimos spiners se muestran con una letra mas chica que el primero que dice Es un Taller, y probando en dispositivos reales en algunos casos ni siquiera se visualiza el elemento seleccionado en los dos spinners de tipo taller y tamaño taller, espero que me puedan dar sugerencias de por que puede estar pasando esto. les dejo el codigo xml de la actividad y una captura de pantalla:

[image: captura de pantalla]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_p"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.sinatsix.josue.jomar.PActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto_saldo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Agregar Taller"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:textColor="@color/textoView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nombreTaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Nombre Taller"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/esCliente"
    android:text="Cliente de JOMAR"
    android:layout_weight="1" />





<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto_es_sucursal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Es un Taller:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/textoView" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/es_sucursal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inpusucursal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Nombre Sucursal"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttipotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Tipo Taller:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/textoView" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tipotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttamanotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Tamaño Taller:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/textoView" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tamanotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelar"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancelar"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textoBoton"
        android:background="@color/fondoBoton"
        android:onClick="irGuardar" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/siguiente"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Siguiente"
        android:textColor="@color/textoBoton"
        android:background="@color/fondoBoton"
        android:onClick="optenerCoordenadas" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: como lo vinculas con la actividad? le agregas propiedades en tu actividad? la vista previa del layout es igual que al ejecutar la aplicación?

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente el layout no tiene alguna propiedad la cual pueda cambiar el color o el estilo del Spinner.

Primer Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/es_sucursal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Segundo Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tipotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    />
```

Tercer Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tamanotaller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```

Incluso el primer Spinner muestra un texto en color negro mientras que los siguientes dos el texto es un gris claro, lo cual no corresponde a lo definido en el layout. Te sugiero agregar tu código para determinar donde se esta realizando el cambio de estilo.